# Database ERD design - Car renting application

Tags: mysql, database, schema, erd

I am designing an entity relationship diagram for our project which is a car renting app. A user will be using the application to book a car renting service. So far this is the database schema that I created. I am wondering in the transaction table, should I just include the payment made by the car renter inside the transaction table or leave it as is?

[image]